# Sort list of DateTime values in descending order including time

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datetime

I have a list of documents. Each document has a *LastModifiedAt* nullable `DateTime` property. Now I want to have a sorted list, which has the latest document on top. E.g.

> 2015-01-26 08:00
>   2015-01-26 07:00
>   2014-12-12 08:00

A simple `OrderByDescending` didn't make the job for me. The document with `2015-01-26 07:00` is on top of the list, whereas it should be on the second position. Then I tried this:

```
documentList.OrderByDescending(d => d.LastModifiedAt.Value.Date).ThenByDescending(d => d.LastModifiedAt.Value.TimeOfDay).ToList();
```

I get the same result that the time is sorted wrong. Additionally I tried

```
documentList.Sort ((x, y) => y.LastModifiedAt.Value.CompareTo (x.LastModifiedAt.Value));
```

but here I get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect the issue is that you are calling `OrderByDescending` on your list but then *not storing the result anywhere* - it doesn't order the original list, it creates a new, ordered sequence.

You need to do something like

```
documentList = documentList.OrderByDescending(d => d.LastModifiedAt.Value).ToList();
```

However, your call to `Sort` is spot on - I can't see why you'd get the error you report.

Edit: as Alexei points out, it's likely that error comes from calling `documentList = documentList.Sort(...)`, which makes it seem unlikely that you're *not* calling `documentList = documentList.OrderByDescending(...)...`.

Comment: Unlikely "The document with 2015-01-26 07:00 is on top of the list" which is definitely not the first one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov We don't know what order the list was in to begin with.

Comment: Maybe... Also I bet OP just removed `list = ... .ToList()` calls to simplify sample (and hide the cause of the second error - real code to get this error have to be `list = documentList.Sort(...)` )

Comment: Now I found the problem: Because I didn't modified the document I thought that the creation date is the same like the modified date. Now I looked into the data and the modifed dates are the same. I don't know why, but the sorting algorithm are working as expected.

Comment: @testing Well, glad to hear you've found your problem at least.

Comment: @Rawling: You spotted me in the right direction. Therefore I gave you the tick.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you sort by the `Date` property of the `DateTime`? Use ...

```
documentList = documentList // you need to re-assign it to the list as Rawling has already mentioned
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastModifiedAt ?? DateTime.MinValue)
    .ToList();
```

Note that i've used the `??` operator to replace nulls with `DateTime.MinValue`, otherwise you're getting an exception if you try to use the `Value` property of the `DateTime?`.

If you want to sort the original list or don't want to use LINQ:

```
documentList.Sort((doc1, doc2) => (doc2.LastModifiedAt ?? DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(doc1.LastModifiedAt ?? DateTime.MinValue));
```

Comment: He does say that he tried a simple `OrderByDescending` first *before* splitting out the `Date` property.

Comment: I don't know why but the latest document isn't at the top of my list.

Comment: @Rawling: i guess that he added the `ThenByDescending` then.

Comment: Also, the sort you ask "Why" about *is a correct sort* even if it's overly complex. There must be something else at work.

Comment: Also, your `List.Sort` example is ascending, not descending.

Comment: @Rawling: fixed the sorting. Note that i've mentioned the need to re-assign the result of the query to the original list as you have already done.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks. I'll use your sorting algorithm because it's better than mine. I found the cause of my problem: The data itself was wrong (the documents had the same date).